# Magento 2 : Custom controller for frontend redirected to 404 page

Tags: magento2, controllers, frontend, 404-page

I have a created a frontend controller on location 
Namespace/Mymodule/Controller/Schedule.php

```
namespace Namespace\Mymodule\Controller;
class Schedule extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function execute()
  {
    die("Hello");
  }
}
```

routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
     <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
        <module name="Namespace_Mymodule" />
    </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

Now when I try to manually call this action by http://localhost/magento2/mymodule/schedule (as i am working on localhost) that time I am getting an 404-Not found page.

Where I am going to wrong ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller structure is wrong  it shold be look like  Namespace/Mymodule/Controller/Index/Schedule.php

URL is: http://localhost/magento2/mymodule/index/schedule

change namespace to Namespace\Mymodule\Controller\index

Answer (score 2):

You can check if you put routes.xml in the wrong place. I also have the same problem , And I finally figured out that I should create the file in this path

```
app/etc/frontend/routes.xml
```

instead of `app/etc/routes.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Create controller Namespace\Mymodule\Controller\Schedule\Index.php

add below code:

```
namespace Namespace\Mymodule\Controller\Schedule;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function execute()
  {
    die("Hello");
  }
}
```